# r multiple joins from list of data frames of differing lengths and differing keys

Tags: r, list, dataframe, left-join

Let's say I've got this list of data frames:

```
library(tidyverse)
df_list <- list(data.frame(cheese = c("ex","ok","bd"), 
                          cheese_val = c(3:1), 
                          stringsAsFactors = F),
               data.frame(egg = c("great","good","bad", "eww"), 
                          egg_val = c(4:1),
                          stringsAsFactors = F),
               data.frame(milk = c("good","bad"), 
                          milk_val = c(2:1), 
                          stringsAsFactors = F))
```

And I've got this core data set:

```
core_dat <- data.frame(cheese = c("ex","ok","ok", "bd", "ok"), 
                      egg = c("great", "bad", "bad", "eww", "great"), 
                      milk = c("good", "good", "good", "bad", "good"), 
                      stringsAsFactors = F)
```

I'd like to get `core_dat` joined individually with each element of `df_list`.

I then tried this:

```
for(i in 1:length(df_list)) {
  gg<-core_dat %>% 
    left_join(df_list[[i]], by = names(df_list[[i]][1]), copy = T)
}
```

which ran but only applied the join to the `milk` column such that the only additional column in `core_dat` was `milk_val` but I expected to see `cheese_val`, and `egg_val` too.

I suspect there are more appropriate options than a for loop here and I am looking for suggestions.  Note that my actual data set has many more df's than this small example.

I should not that I expect the resulting data frame, in this case `gg`, to contain 6 columns total (3 standard name + 3 with "val" suffix) such that it looks like printed version of this:

```
data.frame(cheese = c("ex","ok","ok", "bd", "ok"), 
                      egg = c("great", "bad", "bad", "eww", "great"), 
                      milk = c("good", "good", "good", "bad", "good"), 
                      chees_val = c(3, 2, 2, 1, 2), 
                      egg_val = c(4, 2, 2, 1, 4), 
                      milk_val = c(2, 2, 2, 1, 2))
```

I've seen many "multiple joins" answers here but none that quite line up with what I'm trying to accomplish here (differing key columns, differing lengths of data).

Comment: try `map(df_list, left_join, core_dat)` or `right_join` not sure what is the expected output

Comment: you can do `lapply(df_list,merge,core_data)`

Comment: @missuse - `map` didn't provide the desired result: I updated the question a bit more.

Comment: can we see your desired output? for this example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `map` to get a list of joined data frames, then use `reduce` to join them all together.

```
map(df_list, right_join, rownames_to_column(core_dat)) %>%
  reduce(full_join)
# Joining, by = "cheese"
# Joining, by = "egg"
# Joining, by = "milk"
# Joining, by = c("cheese", "rowname", "egg", "milk")
# Joining, by = c("cheese", "rowname", "egg", "milk")
#   cheese cheese_val rowname   egg milk egg_val milk_val
# 1     ex          3       1 great good       4        2
# 2     ok          2       2   bad good       2        2
# 3     ok          2       3   bad good       2        2
# 4     bd          1       4   eww  bad       1        1
# 5     ok          2       5 great good       4        2
```

Comment: I am confused by the number of records being over the original `core_data` qty of 5.

Comment: I've added row ids to make it have the desired number of rows.

Comment: This worked on my small example *and* my 43-variable version, too - thank you!

Answer (score 2):

This should give the desired output:

```
Reduce(merge,c(df_list,list(core_dat)))
  cheese   egg milk cheese_val egg_val milk_val
1     bd   eww  bad          1       1        1
2     ex great good          3       4        2
3     ok   bad good          2       2        2
4     ok   bad good          2       2        2
5     ok great good          2       4        2
```

Comment: This worked on my small example but in my original data I ran out of memory.

Comment: how big is your data? This is a base R solution. Try the `dplyr` solution. I cant write it as it is already given