# Join tibbles in list to one tibble

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, tidyr, purrr

I have a list of two data frames

```
a = list(
        mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-vs), 
        mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% sample_n(17)
    )
```

and add a new column to the data sets by

```
b = a %>% 
    map(~ mutate(.x, class = floor(runif(nrow(.x), 0, 2)))) %>%
    map(~ nest(.x, -class))
```

Now I want to join the two list elements to one tibble based on `class`. Specifically, I am looking for a "smoother" solution than `inner_join(pluck(b, 1), pluck(b, 2), "class")` which gives the desired results but quickly gets messy if more data sets are involved in the list `a`.

Comment: Join them how? Like a row-bind? Or a left- or inner-join?

Comment: Like an inner join

Comment: You can pipe this into `reduce` with `left_join` or `inner_join`, joining by `class`. Similar to https://stackoverflow.com/q/48452421/5325862

Comment: Ah maybe I should have made that clear. I with the above code I get a list with two tibbles in it. The tibbles have class as first column and tibbles as second column. I want to merge the tibbles in the list _but_ keep the tibbles in the tibbles unaffected (that is, I don't want to merge the tibbles in the tibbles but only the tibbles in the list)

Comment: Can you post an example output?

Comment: `inner_join(pluck(b, 1), pluck(b, 2), "class")` is what I want basically. But I thought that there may be a purrr/tidyverse solution that immediately combines the list elements.

Comment: There might be, but it's hard to know without seeing your intended output. You can [edit] that into the question

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This question is not super clear, but it seemed like there might be enough use cases to go for it. I added a few more data frames to `a`, constructed similarly, because the sample you used is too small to really see what you need to deal with.

```r
library(tidyverse)

set.seed(123)
a <- list(
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(-vs), 
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% sample_n(17),
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% slice(1:10),
  mtcars %>% as_tibble() %>% select(mpg, cyl, disp)
) 
# same construction of b as in the question
```

You can use `purrr::reduce` to carry out the `inner_join` call repeatedly, returning a single data frame of nested data frames. That's straightforward enough, but I couldn't figure out a good way to supply the `suffix` argument to the join, which assigns `.x` and `.y` by default to differentiate between duplicate column names. So you get these weird names:

```r
b %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = "class")
#> # A tibble: 2 x 5
#>   class data.x            data.y           data.x.x         data.y.y       
#>   <dbl> <list>            <list>           <list>           <list>         
#> 1     1 <tibble [11 × 10… <tibble [8 × 11… <tibble [3 × 11… <tibble [17 × …
#> 2     0 <tibble [21 × 10… <tibble [9 × 11… <tibble [7 × 11… <tibble [15 × …
```

You could probably deal with the names by creating something like `data1`, `data2`, etc before the `reduce`, but the quickest thing I decided on was replacing the suffixes with just the index of each data frame from the list `b`. A more complicated naming scheme would be a task for a different question.

```r
b %>%
  reduce(inner_join, by = "class") %>%
  rename_at(vars(starts_with("data")), 
            str_replace, "(\\.\\w)+$", as.character(1:length(b))) %>%
  names()
#> [1] "class" "data1" "data2" "data3" "data4"
```